# how to display and get geo location of a user in ionic app v1 with cordova geolocation plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

Here i am using cordova Geo location plugin to fetch the Geo location of the user and display it on the map to confirm it. when i opened the map view empty page is displayed

here is my code

In index.html

```
<ion-nav-view>

</ion-nav-view>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBvKglWdbBXQc6fL7y1GO8gIVc0"></script>
```

In map.html

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller code

```
 .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        console.log($scope.map);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: latLng,
                icon:'http://i.imgur.com/fDUI8bZ.png'
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "Here You Are.!"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
        });
    }, function(error){
        console.log("Could not get location");
    });
})
```

When i check with console
       console.log(position.coords.latitude);
            console.log(position.coords.longitude);
 iam getting the data but when checked through console in latLng object everything is null.

```
   console.log(latLng);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting position.coords.lat and long then your cordova geolocation must be working.

You don't need to create your latLng object the way you did, you can simply do:

`var latLng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude}`